# How many is "A bunch"?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If someone has assembled the [Deceiver Exarch](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Deceiver%20Exarch)/[Splinter Twin](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Splinter%20Twin) combo, and they say "make a bunch of dudes and kill you", without telling me the number, what happens?

The problem with asking him is that this is a situation where the player is committing a minor rules violation — he's not proposing a proper shortcut — and he gets rewarded for doing that by getting free information: he knows that I'm interested in the number of Deceiver Exarchs that he's making

Is there a way to handle this situation without rewarding my opponent with free information?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you really interested in the number? Surely no one is going to say, okay, I'll make exactly enough to take you down to zero, and you don't have a way to kill 500 tokens that won't kill all of them, do you?

Comment: @Jefromi, I can imagine that cards like Batwing Brume care

Comment: @Jefromi and rakdos charm too.  The big problem is that most exarch-twin players will start playing around rakdos charm if I ask them how many tokens that they're making

Comment: Oh okay, right. Maybe you can figure out how to ask them so casually that they'll say "a million" and hand it to you!

Comment: "and kill you" is not an accepted shortcut. Force your opponent to go through the motions every time, regardless as to whether or not you can do anything.

Comment: I would simply say "I do not concede, please play it out."  The scenario, despite opponent's sloppy communication, isn't ultimately that functionally different from simply playing splinter twin then asking if you concede without doing the combo at all, which is perfectly allowed, and is just as likely or not to telegraph that you believe you are holding an out.

Comment: @Affe have you ever actually tried that?  In my experience it's rare that simply not conceding will get them to tell you a number.

Answer (score 13):

There's not a lot you can do to screw over a player for being vague. Because the rules-provided answer is basically "Force them to be less vague."

Really what players are doing when they say they make "a bunch" of tokens is telling their opponent "Look, I have my combo. Gonna scoop now?" If you do anything other than scoop, *of course* they're gonna play more tightly — since now they're actually playing it out.

**Get in the habit of always asking for clarification. Then you're not giving away any information about your own plan.**

About the most "underhanded" things you can legitimately do are:

- Ask really casually and hope they say something a little more definite.

  > "So, that's what, a million damage heading my way?"
  > "Yup."
  > "After blockers, I'll [Rakdos Charm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rakdos%20Charm)."

  I think most competitive players would call a judge on you and you'd end up in an annoying argument about who exactly said what when. You might also develop a reputation for pettiness of poor sportsmanship.
- Ask someone to slow it down and show you the combo steps. As they do so, they'll probably announce a specific number as part of a shortcut. (This works better with Rakdos Charm than [Batwing Brume](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Batwing%20Brume), because you can do it while they execute the combo instead of having to wait for them to declare attackers.) This is a trick that may actually get you some wins against the more complex combo decks, when they just straight-up botch their combo.

Comment: "Underhanded" sounds like it's bad and something I should avoid based on that first example. Could you give a couple of examples of _good_ conduct for this scenario?

Comment: @JonathanHobbs I did: "Get in the habit of always asking for clarification. Then you're not giving away any information."

Comment: @AlexP That only works if you can force everyone else to always ask for clarification too.

Comment: It's "underhanded" because you're trying for a "gotcha" moment. I don't think it's Bad per se, since you're simply using the same trick they're using. But making them walk through the motions *every* time is the smarter play, since it can force them to play around cards you don't have (not to mention just proper play).

Comment: @SamIam Not necessarily - if you *always* ask for clarification, then the opponent doesn't gain information on whether the answer matters particularly in *this* instance. (Maybe you have the Charm this time, maybe you don't. If you ask both times, they don't know if this is the one they should worry about).

Comment: @AllenGould That only works if you can force everyone else to always ask for clarification too.

Comment: Ideally, What I hope to be able to do is to call a judge, and get the opposing player some sort warning for a communication error for not proposing his shortcut properly.

Comment: @SamIam I don't see why - the goal here is to avoid giving away information. Specifically, that asking for the specific number gives away that you have an answer in hand (and that you haven't been asking when you don't have an answer). Asking for the details everytime (whether you care about the answer or not) means that they don't get additional information, beyond that you're a stickler for the rules.

Comment: @AllenGould when you ask, you tell your opponent that you are a person who might care about the number.  Most people will just assume that it doesn't matter, and scoop, but you're special, You care about the number.  You might be running rakdos charm in your deck.  **Until you can stop getting other people to tell your opponent that they don't run rakdos charm, there is no way for you to avoid telegraphing to your opponent that you do.**

Comment: @SamIam "Other Magic players are lazy, but I can't punish them for being lazy because when I tell them to stop being lazy they actually make correct plays." "Okay, about all you can do is to fish for the information while still encouraging their general lazy attitude, so they don't notice quite as often." "That won't work because other OTHER Magic players are so lazy that they never do that, so they'll know something is amiss!"

Answer (score 4):

According to the Comprehensive Rules on shortcuts:

> **716.2a** At any point in the game, the player with priority may suggest a shortcut by describing a sequence of game choices, for all players, that may be legally taken based on the current game state and the predictable results of the sequence of choices. This sequence may be a non-repetitive series of choices, *a loop that repeats a specified number of times*, multiple loops, or nested loops, and may even cross multiple turns.

(Emphasis mine)

This rule is never contradicted in the Tournament Rules and should thus hold true to any play environment.

This rule states that a shortcut loop requires that the number of iterations of the loop be specified.  Therefore, an arbitrary number of loop iterations (such as "a bunch") is never a legal shortcut.  You should get in the habit of always specifying an exact number of loop iterations when declaring shortcuts such as this, and ask that your opponents do the same.  No information about any player's plans is given away if the rule is applied consistently.

In your situation, I would simply say,

"You have to specify how many *a bunch* is."

This language ("you have to") shows that you're just requesting the shortcut rules be followed properly, not that you're necessarily interested in the exact number, or have a number in mind that would please you.

Comment: Really, there's no reason not to say a defined but absurdly large number, like "one billion."  You're not going to need more than a billion damage.

Comment: @Southpaw See the answer above.  In some cases, doing more than you need can end up killing you instead, so you might not always want to go with one billion...

Comment: @bwarner Well yeah, I get that - in some cases you'd either want a big number or a small number - however, if you're going to big a big number, I don't see a reason not to just pick one.  Either say a reasonable number like "20," or a big one like "a billion."

Comment: We used to have this house rule that let you generate infinities here. Took calculus to resolve games but hey we were all upper division college students.